# Eigenvalues of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Why does a symmetric matrix with elements in $\mathbb R$ have all eigenvalues in $\mathbb R$? How do you show that?

Comment: Related theorem: The eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real.

Comment: Just curious: isn't this proved in almost every introductory text on linear algebra? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @user1551 At the proof itself, in my course there was no such introduction...

Comment: see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124875/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-matrices-are-real-without-complex-numbers

Comment: Also related: [If A is a real symmetric matrix, then A has real eigenvalues.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908417/if-a-is-a-real-symmetric-matrix-then-a-has-real-eigenvalues)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, then $A$ has real eigenvalues.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908417/if-a-is-a-real-symmetric-matrix-then-a-has-real-eigenvalues)

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842366/eigenvalue-of-multiplicity-k-of-a-real-symmetric-matrix-has-exactly-k-linearly-i?rq=1 and countless other questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A$ be a real symmetric $n\times n$-matrix. Suppose that $Av=\lambda v$, i.e. $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Consider the standard Hermitian product $\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\overline{Y_i}$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
 \lambda\left\langle v,v\right\rangle&=& \left\langle \lambda v,v\right\rangle \\
&=& \left\langle Av,v\right\rangle\\
&=& \left\langle v,A^tv\right\rangle \:\: (\mbox{ in general }\left\langle v,A^*v\right\rangle, \mbox{ where $A^*$ denotes $\overline{A}^t$})\\
&=& \left\langle v,Av\right\rangle\\
&=& \left\langle v,\lambda v\right\rangle\\
&=& \overline{\lambda}\left\langle v,v\right\rangle.
\end{eqnarray}

Hence $(\lambda-\overline{\lambda})\left\langle v,v\right\rangle=0$. But $\left\langle v,v\right\rangle\neq 0$ as $v$ is an eigenvector hence $(\lambda-\overline{\lambda})=0$, in other words, $\lambda$ is real.

In a very similar fashion you can show that eigenvectors belonging to different eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal. Try that as an exercise.

**Edit:** As indicated in the comments below, we also prove that eigenvalues for $A$ exist. Consider the characteristic polynomial $p_A(X)$ of $A$. A priori $p_A(X)\in \mathbb{R}[X]$, but similarly as above (where we considered a complex inner-product rather than a real one), we have that $p_A(X)\in \mathbb{C}[X]$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, $p_A(X)=\prod_{i=1}^n(X-\lambda_i)$ for certain not necessarily distinct $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{C}$. Then the $\lambda_i$ are complex eigenvalues and by the reasoning above they are real.

Comment: Although this answers a rather narrow interpretation of the Question (if an eigenvalue exists, it must be real), I suspect the OP really meant to ask how to prove that real eigenvalues (of an appropriate quantity) *exist* for any real symmetric matrix.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks for pointing that out, I added an explanation.